# In Objective-c++, is there a way to move static c functions to another file?

Tags: objective-c++

At work, I see lots of ObjC++ files that have dozens of static C helper functions at the top. I'd like to break these static C helper functions out into a separate file and just import the header to ease readability.

Instead of:

```
static int _AddEm(const int a, const int b) { return a + b }
...
...
...
x 300
```

Something like:

```
#import "MyClassHelpers.h"
```

That would contain all the static C helper functions. The issue is that static seems to only work in the declared file (I'm coming from a Swift and Java background), so I can't just declare a static class in c++ world and bring it and it's helpers over. I'd like to maintain the speed and binary size benefits of using static. What's the best practice for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, putting `static` on a function means that the function is restricted to the file where it's declared. (And as a result you can have `static` functions with the same name in multiple files without conflicting, whereas without `static` the linker may complain of multiple functions with the same name.) In a way, you can think of it as making the function "private" to the file (in the sense of private members of a class in object-oriented languages you might be familiar with).

If you want to define the code of a function once and use it in multiple files, you want the opposite -- make it *not* `static`, and then declare the function signature in the header with `extern`, like this:

```
// in MyClassHelpers.h
extern int _AddEm(const int a, const int b);

// in MyClassHelpers.c
int _AddEm(const int a, const int b) { return a + b }
```

This way, other files that include `MyClassHelpers.h` can use this function, and the linker will link it with the the single implementation of it compiled from `MyClassHelpers.c`.

If you had put a `static` function definition in the header like this:

```
// in MyClassHelpers.h
static int _AddEm(const int a, const int b) { return a + b }
```

then each implementation file that includes this header will effectively have its own "private" copy of this function, potentially resulting in the same code being repeated numerous times. (Including a header is basically the same as copy-pasting the contents of the header into the file it is included in, so it is if you wrote this static function definition in every file.)

It occurs to me that perhaps what you're trying to do with these tiny functions is to have calls to them be *inlined* rather than be called as separate function calls. In that case, perhaps declaring it `static` and `inline` in the header will work:

```
// in MyClassHelpers.h
static inline int _AddEm(const int a, const int b) { return a + b }
```